# Error Message of required Input in jQuery UI accordion

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui, jquery

I've got the following Problem:

I arranged multiple input-fields in an accordion (jQuery UI). Some of the input-field are required through the `required`-attribute. 
When I want to submit my form, the error message shown from the Browser don't get the right position if this input-field is hidden in the accordion.

HTML:

```
<form>
  <div class="accordion">
    <h3>Header One</h3>
    <div>
      <input type="text" required="required" />
    </div>
    <h3>Header One</h3>
    <div>
      <input type="text" required="required" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Look at the example in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m2n31r3t/)

Just hit submit and the error-message will show at the left-bottom corner of the browser.

Does anyone has an idea how to avoid this behaviour or how to style the message ? (if possibly without custom error-messages)

Comment: Have you resolved your problem?

Comment: @mtb I guess not, but considering the question's 4 years old by now the circumstances might have changed regarding this